# Can't import com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.TableCell

Tags: java, google-bigquery

In our sourcecode, I can import library for 'import com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.TableRow;
import com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.*;'
But I can't import 'import com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.TableCell;'
Please tell me know to solve this case.
Thanks,
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYCiN.png)

Answer (score 1):

From the image that you have attached,there is no class as TableCell in your jar file.

```
1.Check the jar file whether it contains the TableCell class by extracting it
2.Download the latest version,remove the existing jar file and include the latest version again.
```

The package does contain TableCell class.So I can only assume it is missing in the jar file that you are using

https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/bigquery/v2/java/latest/com/google/api/services/bigquery/model/package-tree.html